# Where to place code for global access in MVC multi tenant application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

.Net 4.6.1 MVC

I placed the following test code in the Index action of the HomeController to test deciphering of the Host name for multi tenancy.

*Where should the code be placed so that the Host or Tenant info can be accessible globally in the application?

Once the host or tenant is obtained from the URL and host data retrieved from the database should the data be stored in a session or retrieved with every request?*

```
  string host = string.Empty;
  host = Request.Url.Host;

        int portNumberIndex = host.LastIndexOf(':');
        if (portNumberIndex > 0)
        {
            host = host.Substring(0, portNumberIndex);
        }

        ViewData["hostName"] = host;
```

Comment: You can store it in Session or on the browser with local storage. You can store it in a "temporary" database table. Depends on how you're using the data. If you're just extracting the host name for display and want to do it for every request you can move this to a Child Action.

Comment: Store it in the httpcontext.items dictionary.  take a look at SaasKit https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit